# Pagination for a query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this functions to get all rows from anunturi table with ajax.

```
function view_user_anunt($user) {


         $query="SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
         FROM anunturi t1 
         INNER JOIN tranzactie t2 ON t1.tranzactie = t2.id_tranzactie
         INNER JOIN tip_proprietate t3 ON t1.tip = t3.id_prop
         WHERE t1.user=:code 
";

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':code', $user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $nr=$stmt->rowCount();
        echo $nr;
        foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $result) 
        {
            $view[]="
            <tr>
            <td>".$result['id_anunt']."</td>
            <td>".$result['den_tranzactie']."</td>
            <td>".$result['den_prop']."</td>
            <td>hehe</td>
            <td><a href='#' id='vizualizare'>Select</a></td>
            <td><a href='#' id='modificare'>Select</a></td>
            </tr>";

        }

    return $view;



}
```

}

I need a solution to paginate this query.
If is possible I need to be paginated with ajax and php.
Thanks in advance....

Comment: extend query with `LIMIT offse, rows_per_page`

Comment: The question is not fit for [SO], as there is no attempt to solve the problem. But I have to make note : **This code uses DBO prepared statement the way it is meant to be!** That is a nice change from all the SQL injection crap out there...

Comment: Give Start Limit & End Limit in your Query,(1) https://github.com/thiswolf/php-jquery-pagination (2) http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27581/my-method-of-php-ajax-pagination   this 2 link will help you

Comment: This isn't a question. Paginating your data would require a significant chunk of work, even outside the scope of your function. You should Google it (`paginating MySQL results in PHP`) and then come back to StackOverflow if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't write the ready code not to encourage spoon-feeding but can show you the way. First thing to do is defining page variable and set it to a default number (1 for the first page for example). Then, you should find out how many pages there are by counting the records and dividing it to the number of posts you want to show on each page. By having the page count variable, now you should be able to display page number links on the page. Each page link should go to same original page, with a get variable like /example.php?page=2

The next step is to call only the related records from database. Lets say page is 4 and you show 10 records on each page. For this case, you should pass first 30 records and call only 10 records. You can do this easily with limit and offset.